# Selenium wait not solving error "Element is not currently visible"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got an error:

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds

So I added "wait" object to wait for the html obj to load:

```
   val wait: WebDriverWait  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("company_id")))

   val selectCompany = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("company_id")))
    selectCompany.selectByValue("975")
```

but still i get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed
>   out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id:
>   company_id

and I dont get it since the html is:

```
<select class="upload_company_id jcf-hidden" id="company_id" name="company_id" size="2"><option value="">Select account...</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="101">101</option>
<option value="104">104</option>
<option value="975">105</option>
```

this is more of the html:

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the expected condition you choosed is right.The class you are using is select class. Could you please try [elementToBeSelected](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeSelected-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)(WebElement element)?

Comment: can you show me an example how to use  elementToBeSelected?

Comment: Exactly what you wrote in your code just change the method

Comment: val wait: WebDriverWait  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.id("company_id")));

    val selectCompany = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("company_id")))
    selectCompany.selectByValue("975")

Answer (score 0):

What you need to check is the computed CSS values of the element you are clicking. (In Chrome web inspector select the Computed tab on the right).
Selenium thinks that an element is hidden and can't be interacted with if any of these CSS values are set for the element:

- `display=none` or
- `visibility=hidden` or
- `visibility=collapse`

If you can find any of these values on the computed tab, you will have to use JS to click on the element, or change the CSS value of the element on some way - Selenium will refuse interacting with the element regardless of the actual visibility of it. (I suspect the problem will be the "jcf-hidden" class)

---

When inspecting the element, switch to this tab in Chrome inspector on the right side:
[image: Chrome inspector] 
and look for any of the mentioned values in the list.

Comment: can you try to guid me with more info please, im a beginner with selenium and dont know much? I tried to look By.cssSelector and copied the css path, BUT, its not uniq...the only uniq thing is the class name. but also the issue is that there is a div that is wrapping the <select >" line

Comment: added an image to the question, take a look

Comment: Updated the answer a bit to see if this is the case at all.

Comment: display: block;
there is no visibility there

Comment: Usually when i right click on a dropdown and click "inspect element" I get strait to the <select ... /select> line, but now the line I was directed to was the <div.../div> line. do you know why? and maybe this is part of the errror?

Comment: If it's populated by JS, it might cause this issue also. Do you see any visibility attributes if you manually select an `option` from the source in the inspector?

Comment: Actually the "select" item's css visibility might be more relevant.

Comment: http://d.pr/i/1cP8u/3OH4REVU there you go, this screenshot might help you understand something

Comment: As I can see still the div is selected. Click on the `select` tag, and check the computed tab again. Meanwhile could you also post some code how you are trying to interact with the list?

Comment: val wait: WebDriverWait  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.className("upload_company_id jcf-hidden")))

    val selectCompany = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("upload_company_id jcf-hidden")))
    selectCompany.selectByValue("975")

Comment: this is how i try to interact with it, i try to find it by class name cause its the only uniq value there. there is another select apparently with the same id